# How to install mssql in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, freetds

Installed freetds

/etc/odbcinst.ini

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = ODBC for Microsoft SQL
Driver      = /usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so
UsageCount  = 1
Threading   = 2
```

/etc/odbc.ini

```
[myserver-connector]
Description     = MS SQL connection to 'asterisk' database
Driver          = FreeTDS
Database        = mydb
Server          = 192.168.100.1
UserName        = sampleuser
Password        = password
Trace           = No
TDS_Version     = 7.0
Port            = 1433
```

`echo "select 1" | isql -v myserver-connector`

I got following error message:

`[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so' : file not found
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect`

Comment: You can use the apt-file utility to see if there's a package that provides that .so file.

Answer (score 4):

`sudo apt-get install php5-odbc php5-sybase tdsodbc`

/etc/odbc.ini

```
# Define a connection to the MSSQL server.
# The Description can be whatever we want it to be.
# The Driver value must match what we have defined in /etc/odbcinst.ini
# The Database name must be the name of the database this connection will connect to.
# The ServerName is the name we defined in /etc/freetds/freetds.conf
# The TDS_Version should match what we defined in /etc/freetds/freetds.conf
[mssql]
Description             = Microsoft SQL Server
Driver                  = freetds
Database                = XXXXXXXXXX
ServerName              = mssql
TDS_Version             = 8.0
```

/etc/odbcinst.ini

```
# Define where to find the driver for the Free TDS connections.
[freetds]
Description     = MS SQL database access with Free TDS
Driver          = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
UsageCount      = 1
```

/etc/freetds/freetds.conf

```
# The basics for defining a DSN (Data Source Name)
# [data_source_name]
#       host = <hostname or IP address>
#       port = <port number to connect to - probably 1433>
#       tds version = <TDS version to use - probably 8.0>

# Define a connection to the freitrater/EBE server.
[mssql]
        host = mssql.domain
        port = 1433
        tds version = 8.0
```

Notice the location of the .so objects defined in /etc/odbcinst.ini!

Comment: I have followed same steps but not success , again I have the same error.

Comment: What do you see when you execute: `ls -l /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/`?

Comment: I am getting following files list                                     libesoobS.so libmimerS.so  libnn.so  libodbcdrvcfg1S.so
libodbcdrvcfg2S.so libodbcminiS.so libodbcmyS.so libodbcnnS.so libodbcpsqlS.so libodbctxtS.so liboplodbcS.so liboraodbcS.so libsapdbS.so libtdsS.so

Comment: Are you using 32-bit or 64-bit OS? If 64-bit, look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031897/missing-libtdsodbc-so-in-freetds-dev-mssql-on-ubuntu