# django-pyodbc: Data source name not found, and no default driver specified

Tags: pyodbc, django-pyodbc

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 server, Django 1.5.5, pyodbc-3.0.7 and I am trying to connect to a MSSQL 2005 server. I've installed django-pyodbc through pip and modified my settings.py like so:

```
 DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_pyodbc', 
        'NAME': 'db_name',                     
        'USER': 'user_name',                    
        'PASSWORD': 'password',              
        'HOST': 'AB131\A_INS01',                  
        'PORT': '',                    
        'OPTIONS': {
           'host_is_server': True
        },
    }
}
```

But when I try to run syncdb I get:

```
 Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

The ODBC driver installed on the Windows machine is:

```
  SQL Server 6.01.7601.17514 SQLSRV32.DLL
```

What else do I need to do? Are there any other drivers that I need to install on either the Linux or Windows machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a driver installed on the django-pyodbc application server.

Take a look at [FreeTDS install instructions](https://code.google.com/p/django-pyodbc/wiki/FreeTDS) on the django-pyodbc project page.

Replace `tsodbc` package with `tdsodbc` in the [install section](https://code.google.com/p/django-pyodbc/wiki/FreeTDS#Installing_FreeTDS). [Issue 130](https://code.google.com/p/django-pyodbc/issues/detail?id=130&thanks=130&ts=1390571961) has been entered to correct the wiki entry.

Alternately this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17147906/366335) may help fill in the rough patches of the django-pyodbc docs.

Comment: I'm getting **E: Unable to locate package tsodbc**

Answer (score -1):

first stape
$ sudo apt-get install libmdbodbc1

edit the file /etc/odbcinst.ini like this

```
[Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)]
Description = Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)
Driver      = /path/to/file/libmdbodbc.so
Setup       = /path/to/file/libtdsS.so
CPTimeout   = 
CPReuse     =
```

And the file /etc/odbc.ini

```
[Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)]
Description         = SQL Server
Driver              = Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)
Trace               = No
TraceFile           = /tmp/mssodbc.log
```